Stepper Motor Driver Output Frequency
I am working on a project with NEMA8 stepper motors, and I am using an DRV8825 driver controlled by an STM microcontroller. However, I noticed that the driver output does not match my expectations based on internet sources. The output (the signal above in the picture) is inconsistent and has a frequency much higher than the frequency of the input (the signal below), even though the driver output should theoretically have a lower frequency. I am using a 24V/0.6A supply voltage, which are the rated voltage/current of the motor. Does anyone know why the driver output could be like this?


Which microstep mode did you configure?

without details, my guess is the stall current on the motor is twice your supply limit and PWM is limiting the current on one leg.

some clone boards have the jumpers that set up the driver microstepping wired incorrectly. do a quick search on the part numbers to check.

I don't have microstepping set, so the driver is outputting full steps. I double checked the output signal, and it looks like it's supposed to when the motor isn't connected. When I connect the motor, the output signal goes crazy, but the motor moves just fine.

In the TI datasheet section 8.3.2 it talks about fixed frequency pwm used for current regulation. That’s what you’re seeing.
